# Angularjs controller Issue with REST call

Tags: angularjs, rest

I'm trying to create a simple web page that will load a series of keyword libraries from a database, and then display them. In our java code, I have a REST interface that fields the request and does the database queries, then returns the data, but when I load the page it never issues the REST request.  I apologize if this is a very basic error - I have experience with Java and Python, but I've never really worked with HTML or angularjs before.  Here is the HTML page [Updated 4:36pm EST]:

```
<div ng-cloak>
<head ng-app="trmApp"></head>
  <h1>Robot Keyword Libraries</h1>
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
    <md-tab label="Keyword Documentation">
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <div class="main" ng-controller="getKwDocs">
          <button id="Get Keywords" ng-click="loadKwData()">Get Keywords</button>
          <div ng-repeat="data in kwData">
            <h3> {{ data }} </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </md-content>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
</div>
```

And here is the controller [UPDATED 4:36pm EST]:

```
angular.module('trmApp').controller('getKwDocs', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loadKwData = function() {
        console.log('Method called');
        $http.get('/trm/kw_test').success(
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.kwData = response;
            })
        .error(console.error('Failed');
        };
    });
```

Any help steering me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work without using ng-init() just simply call the function inside the controller?

Comment: can you set $scope.kwData=["hello"] and do you see the value?

Comment: Thanks - I tried both of those suggestions, but neither change the behavior. I tried temporarily adding another header to print just {{ kwData }} before the ng-repeat line, but it still just displays it as a literal '{{ kwData }}'

Comment: Can you get rid off ng-init and call $scope.loadKwData() into controller, after the function $scope.loadKwData()? Try also, console.log(data) to see if the server are returning some data

Comment: Which angularjs version are you running ? $http(..).success(...) won't work with angularjs >=1.6

Comment: did you add ng-app to your html head? is console giving any errors?

Comment: I removed the ng-init call and added a console log message as the first line in the controller's function loadKwData - the message never appears when I click the button.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN It's being used elsewhere in the code (and working) so the versioning should be okay.

Comment: @RobertI The console doesn't throw any errors, I don't see anything at all there. I tried altering the first line of the controller to "angular.module('trmApp').angular.controller('getKwDocs', function($scope, $http) {"  and then added the ng-app to the head: "  <head ng-app="trmApp"></head>" but still no luck.

Comment: @jamesknapp if so, don't forget the error callback. With angularjs <1.6 (that you must have). You won't see any error if there is one with only the success callback.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN Ok I added that to the controller, but still when I click on the button nothing happens - no error or anything, like it was never called.  For reference, this is what it looks like after the change: **angular.module('trmApp').angular.controller('getKwDocs', function($scope, $http) {

 // load the keywords
 $scope.loadKwData = function() {
  console.log('loadKwData function called')
  $http.get('/trm/kw_test').success(
  function(response) {
   $scope.kwData = response.data;
  })
  .error(callback)
 };
});**

Comment: @jamesknapp : should'nt it be `$scope.kwData = response;`  ?

Comment: @JulienTASSIN Ok I changed it (still the same behavior though, I don't think it's even getting that far) - I've edited the original post with the current changes so it's easier to see, hopefully that doesn't muddy the waters.

Comment: @jamesknapp What is your error callback look like ? A simple `.error(console.error)` should be enought.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN Ok I changed the error to .error(console.error('Failed')) but I still don't see anything in the console.

Comment: @jamesknapp try doing `$scope.kwData = response.data;`